# Identify If User is Group using the client object model

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I have a sharepoint field in a list that can be either a user or a group. Using the Server Object Model, I can identify easily whether the user is a group or not.

However, I cannot find a way to achieve this using the Managed Client Object model. Is there a way to know.

I only managed to make it work by looping the list of groups and checking if the there is a group with the name. Howver, this is not exactly correct or efficient. Maybe there is a way to find out using the ListItem of the user. But I did not see any fields that show that user is administrator. I have also tried EnsureUser. This crashes if the user is not a group. So I could work out by using a try/catch but this would be very bad programming.

Thanks,

Joseph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this get the list of users from `ClientContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList` and then check the `ContentType` of each item that is returned to determine what it is.

Checking the content type is not very direct though, because all you actually get back from each item is a `ContentTypeID`, which you then have to look-up against the content types of the user list at `ClientContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList.ContentTypes`.  That look-up will return a ContentType object, and you can read from the `Name` property of that object to see what the list item is.

So an over simplified chunk of code to do this would be:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

...

```
ClientContext context = ClientContext.Current;

var q = from i in context.Web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItems(new CamlQuery()) select i;
IEnumerable<ListItem> Items = context.LoadQuery(q);
context.ExecuteQueryAsync((s, e) => {
    foreach (ListItem i in Items) {
        //This is the important bit:
        ContentType contenttype = context.Web.SiteUserInfoList.ContentTypes.GetById(i["ContentTypeId"].ToString());
        context.Load(contenttype); //It's another query so we have to load it too
        switch (contenttype.Name) {
            case "SharePointGroup":
                //It's a SharePoint group
                break;
            case "Person":
                //It's a user
                break;
            case "DomainGroup":
                //It's an Active Directory Group or Membership Role
                break;
            default:
                //It's a mystery;
                break;
        }
    }
},
    (s, e) => { /* Query failed */ }
);
```

You didn't specify your platform, but I did all of this in Silverlight using the SharePoint client object model.  It stands to reason that the same would be possible in JavaScript as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.SearchPrincipals(...)`:

```
var resultPrincipals = Utility.SearchPrincipals(clientContext, clientContext.Web, searchString, PrincipalType.All, PrincipalSource.All, null, maxResults);
```

The return type, `PrincipalInfo`, conveniently has a PrincipalType property which you can check for Group.